What is the procedure for Gandharva Vivaha?
"And so saying, that first of kings "wedded" the handsome Sakuntala of graceful
gait, and knew her as a husband."
Mahabharata Adi Parva: Sambhava Parva: Section LXXIII
Here it says that Dushyanta "wedded" what is the procedure for Gandharva wedding..Is sexual union itself considered wedding or is there any ritual or mantra sankalpa that is considered as wedding? Or saying that "I accept you as my husband" itself is considered wedding?
Or one needs to consummate in order for wedding to be complete?
And can the maiden exit the vivaha before consummation?
Are the details about this form of marriage present in detail in any scripture?
Thanks
